# How to run the test plan with different username in jmeter?

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter

I am recording my web application using JMeter, then i will edit my number of **users (thread) = 2**, so then while running my test plan the user name must be given separate for two users and run the test plan simultaneously **as one must return with correct login and other must return wrong username**. So how to do it with JMeter? Please show me the way with some **screenshots** if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps carefully:

List item

> test plan->Add->Thread(user)->Thread group
>
> thread group->Add->config element->HTTP Request Defaults
>
> thread group->logic controller->recording controller
>
> Workspace->Add->non-test element->http test script recorder

start your plan & record it.after successful creating of test plan do
   the following steps: add the csv data set config in your test plan
   Thread group->add->config element->csv data set config

in csv data set config file give the parameter values like : in
   filename:-give your csv file path & in variable name pass the
   variable as:username,password

in your test plan check the login file in that file change the static
   values username as "${username}" & password "${password}"

pass the different values in csv file & before start the test plan
   change the number of thread you want run

Answer (score 0):

Correct username can be left as is, for the incorrect one you can use [__RandomString()](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-using-functions) function.